# How to join two different tables(without common column) side by side without getting cross join in the output in Mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I want to join two different tables side by side without loosing any row from the tables and the result should not be cross join.

Create table query for t1:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS t1 (
    `i` INT,
    `foo` INT);
INSERT INTO t1 VALUES
    (1,1),
    (2,2),
    (3,3),
    (4,4);
```

Output for t1 table is:

```
i   foo
1   1
2   2
3   3
4   4
```

Create table query for dates table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS dates (
    `User` VARCHAR(2) CHARACTER SET utf8,
    `start_date` date,
    `end_date` date
);
INSERT INTO dates VALUES
    ('U1','2020-01-01','2020-01-31'),
    ('U2','2020-01-16','2020-01-26'),
    ('U3','2020-01-28','2020-02-06');
```

Output for dates table is:

```
User  start_date    end_date
U1    2020-01-01    2020-01-31
U2    2020-01-16    2020-01-26
U3    2020-01-28    2020-02-06
```

BUT I WANT THE OUTPUT LIKE: t1 and dates table side by side

```
i  foo  User   start_date   end_date
1   1    U1    2020-01-01   2020-01-31
2   2    U2    2020-01-16   2020-01-26
3   3    U3    2020-01-28   2020-02-06
4   4    null   null        null
```

Comment: You need a relationship between the two tables to join them.

Comment: Use `LEFT JOIN` to get null values for rows in t1 with no matching row in t2. But what is the matching relationship?

Comment: Is it `t2.user = CONCAT('U', t1.foo)`?

Comment: If the results are unrelated, then it isn't a join, by definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Relational algebra doesn't work this way, so normal joins and unions won't produce the result you want.

You can, however, manufacture a fake key on each data set to join with, using `ROW_NUMBER()`. For example:

```
with a as (
  select *, row_number() over() as rn from t1
),
b as (
  select *, row_number() over() as rn from dates
)
select a.i, a.foo, b.User, b.start_date, b.end_date
from a left join b on a.rn = b.rn
```

**Note**: The solution above assumes `a` has more rows than `b`. If this is not a given the query will need a full join, that unfortunately MySQL does not implement. It can be simulated with a left join and an anti-join, however.

Comment: Thank you so much!